# Is it possible to send current location to server in the background mode on iOS device?

Tags: ios, gps

I want to make an app that sends current GPS location to the server.
This app also needs to work in background mode.
Is it possible to make this kind of app?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. If you have a specific question, please ask that. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's indeed possible. You have to use the `Core Location` API for that.

Background code execution on iOS is quite tricky in general, but location updates are actually one of the few cases which make this possible. Your app receives the right to perform some operations after location updates are received, so you can use these operations to send the new data to the server.

Comment: Do I have to code for background mode?

Comment: What? Are you asking if you have to write code?

Comment: I mean what should I do to work in background mode.

Comment: Well, that's quite complicated, take a look at this article for some guidance: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html And here is the development guide for background execution: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: open GPS in background is forbidden in Apple's document, but if your app is relaunched by significant location change, you can still quick call `startUpdateLocation` to get GPS updates, and don't forget to call `stopUpdateLocation` after. This is confirmed by a Apple engineer during WWDC14.